# Error using pandas.Series.asof: can't compare datetime.datetime to str

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

How is the `Series.asof` function used? I passed in a `datetime` object `datetime.strptime('20150101', '%Y%m%d')`, but why is it giving an error

```
  File "/Users/x/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2460, in asof
    if where < start:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to str
```

Code used is:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

names = ['mary', 'john', 'tom']
dates = [datetime.strptime('20130101', '%Y%m%d'), 
         datetime.strptime('20140101', '%Y%m%d'), 
         datetime.strptime('20150101', '%Y%m%d')]
mySeries = pd.Series(dates, names)

print mySeries.asof(datetime.strptime('20140101', '%Y%m%d'))
```

How am I using it wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data and index are reversed in `mySeries`.  The index needs to be a TimeSeries.

```
mySeries = pd.Series(data=names, index=dates)
>>> print mySeries.asof(datetime.strptime('20140101', '%Y%m%d'))
john
```